# Products is not showing up on Magento2 subcategory

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.0

I installed a fresh magento2, and top categories are working, but for sub-category, there is no product showing up in frontend even thought I assigned products to these sub-categories.

It's always said "We can't find products matching the selection."

Where can I find the code in Magento 2 that's responsible for displaying products so I can diagnose this in a programatic manner?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This question is off-topic here, since SO is a site dedicated to programming questions. Please take the [introductory tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour). Furthermore, your question lacks basic information, like version used and alike. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 4):

**To show the product, check if the product following options:**

1. General->Status = Enabled
2. general->Visibility = Catalog,Search
3. Inventory->Qty > 0
4. Inventory->Stock Availability = In Stock
5. Websites = checking your site
6. Catgories = checking your category.

If you want checking product to subcategory, go to **Catalog->Manage Categories->Select your category**, open tab Display Settings and change option **"Is Anchor"** to **"Yes"**. Save category.

Comment: Which Magento 2 version are you using?

Comment: I am using magento 2.4.1. I tried all your steps but still not showing

Answer (score 3):

You can try reindexing.it works if these things all set

1.General->Status = Enabled

2.general->Visibility = Catalog,Search

3.Inventory->Qty > 0

4.Inventory->Stock Availability = In Stock

5.Websites = checking your site

6.Catgories = checking your category.

Comment: Thank you so much, reindexing did the job! Good to know, had my head wrap around this for a while. Can you explain by any chance what exactly is reindexing used for ?

Comment: In my case, the price has to be present. Use 0.00 if you have none.

Comment: Nice, you stole the answer from @Echo.

Answer (score 3):

Please run the following command in your commandline:

```
php bin/magento indexer:status
```

If one of the indexes is "Processing" then go to your MySQL database and go to the indexer_state table. You will notice that one of the values is "Working" while the rest is "Valid"

Set Working to Invalid and reindex again. The best way to do this is to run the following Query:

```
update magento.indexer_state set status='invalid' where status ='working'
```

Good luck!

Comment: For more information check https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5146

Comment: Note that you can also use bin/magento indexer:reset to avoid having to edit the database.

Answer (score 3):

Sub-category Product show problem solution as you need to follow as below:

**Magento 2 Admin==> Products==>Category==> Sub Category==> Design ==>Use Parent Category Settings==>Checked Here**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is due to reindexing issue.

**app\code\Modules\Catalog\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full" type="Modules\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full" />
</config>
```

**app\code\Modules\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full.php**

```
<?php 
namespace Modules\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action;

/**
 * Class AbstractAction
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
*/

class Full extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full {

    public function isRangingNeeded() {
        return false; // It was "True" as default setting.
    }
}
```

Then, we should run this command.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Finally, we got whole 2000 products on our category page instead of previous 340 products on frontend page. 
Also, the "Product category" tab on index management is just updated from date of version upgraded to current indexing date and time.

**Great experience!**

Hope this will help many developers and owners.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, product showed up in the parent category, but not in the originally assigned subcategory. I solved it by hitting the "Save" button in the subcategory and/or (not sure if both necessary) parent category edit page.

Comment: yes that also works, well a manual reindex, but for me it is much simpler to hit just save in the category page rather than open up the shell coammand, login, change user, run reindex manually and renew the cache. Problem is discussed over here in more detail https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2855

Comment: that's not a correct way to do. What for new products ? Inventory change ? etc... In-fact you could schedule indexing as a cron based on your desire time so that your data is properly indexed.